# SSL Certificates on aws beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl

I'm sorry if this is a simple question but I'm new to aws. I have three beanstalk applications: one with url xxx.domainname.com, another with yyy.domainname.com, and the last zzz.domainname.com. The "domain name.com" part is the same in all. Can I use one SSL certificate for all three beanstalks or or do I need three? Does the certificate apply on the domain or on the application? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use wildcards certificates to protect multiple applications in multiple subdomains.

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wildcard_certificate about wildcard certificates.

See http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/configuring-https.html about AWS Elastic Beanstalk and SSL certificates